# Como compilar un programa desde la consola de visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilador

Hola mi pregunta basicamente es si yo tengo un archivo sea por ejemplo main.cpp es posible compilarlo desde la consola con el compilador y si es así como sería ya que abrir y cerrar visual studio a veces es un poco lento. Entonces es eso basicamente cuando la consola me refiero a:
Símbolo del sistema para desarrolladores de VS2013.
Estuve buscando pero no doy todavía con la tecla.

> El ejemplo sería un main.cpp, compilarlo con el compilador desde
>   consola..

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta está en la documentación: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639.aspx)

Ejemplo hello.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  
void main()  
{  
    cout << "Hello, world, from Visual C++!" << endl;  
}
```

Compilar con el siguiente comando:

```
c:\"tu directorio">cl /EHsc hello.cpp  
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23918 for x86  
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.  

hello.cpp  
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.23918.0  
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.  

/out:hello.exe  
hello.obj
```

Ejecutar:

```
c:\"tu directorio">hello.exe
```

Salida:

```
Hello, world, from Visual C++!
```